# AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython3macOsBrew'

Tags: pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04, cpython, python-3.10

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and wanted to create a project with python3.10, so I installed the python using the deadsnakes PPA, it works fine

```
$ python3.10 Python 3.10.13 (main, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:03) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux Type 
"help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

but when I try to create a virtualenv using the command

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.10 test_env
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython3macOsBrew'
```

Comment: Can you try to upgrade the `virtualenv`(Using `pip install virtualenv -U`) and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM still same issue

Comment: how did you install virtualenv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this error message show up in PyCharm while trying to build venv's for my project.

I rolled back **virtualenv** in my local Python3.9.1 install to version **20.23.0**, then restarted PyCharm which fixed my problem.

`pip uninstall virtualenv`

`pip install virtualenv==20.23.0`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER 2023-09-26:**

It happened again. But, I was able to resolve the problem *much* more easily as follows:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
```

Original answer follows:

---

I'm hitting this error too, albeit actually *on* Mac OS.

Some searching turned up some similar issues (different missing attribute, however) in [this github issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1740).

I'm working under the assumption it's a broken install of `virtualenv`:

```
~$ ~/miniconda3/envs/ManyFEWS/bin/python3.9 -mvirtualenv

AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython3macOsBrew'
```

My virtualenv installed under miniconda was giving the error, but using system python worked:

```
~$ /usr/bin/python3 -mvirtualenv

usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe]
                  [--creator {builtin,cpython3-mac-framework,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed] [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--no-vcs-ignore] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies]
                  [--no-download | --download] [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip] [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--no-periodic-update] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt]
                  [-h]
                  dest
virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest
SystemExit: 2
```

`virtualenv` was perfectly happy in my Conda base environment too.

So, I wiped out my miniconda install and reinstalled, and didn't have the error any more. Musing on a root cause, I wonder if it was because I've been using PyCharm with that environment. Something's been altered by something. Apologies that I can't be more specific!

I appreciate there's several differences in your setup (using a ppa instead of miniconda, as in my case), but I'd encourage you to look at your install.

Instead of using a PPA, could you use a tool like miniconda to manage your environments? This did make it a lot easier for me to wipe mine out and try different things to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an optimal answer, but for people struggling like I did,for the time being, I propose try another alternative of **virtualenv** called **pyenv**, so follow these steps

update the system

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

install dependencies

```
sudo apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \ libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \ xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git
```

install pyenv

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
```

configure environment (open the **bashrc** file via **sudo gedit ~/.bashrc** and save the following)

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"

export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

after making the changes, run the following command to apply them

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

verify the install by

```
pyenv --version
```

install the python version

```
pyenv install 3.10.13
```

the above command will install the python 3.10.13 you could use it in your project folder by the command

```
pyenv local 3.10.13
```

now we need to install **pyenv-virtualenv** which is a tool to create virtual environments integrated with **pyenv** it can be done via
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pyenv-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-18-04/

then once the Python version is installed, you can create a virtual environment using pyenv-virtualenv by

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.13 env_name
```

activate the virtual environment by running

```
pyenv activate env_name
```